# Mid-priced Portable Recorders & Microphone.

Tags: portable-recorder, shotgun, marantz, tascam, rode

Hi,

I'm looking to buy a portable recorder and shotgun microphone.

I want the recorder to have decent internal mic's, to get some nice ambience recordings, but, as I can't really afford an extra pre-amp, I also need xlr input and phantom power.

I think i've narrowed it down to these:
-Marantz PMD661
-Roland R-26
-Tascam DR-100 Mk2

And as for a microphone I am looking to get a Rode NTG-2.

If you have any experience with any of these, or any advice, I would hugely appreciate it, I find it so hard to pick between them.

Thanks

Comment: these questions are pretty common here, and have been answered numerous times. try running a search of the site.

Comment: @Shaun. thanks Shaun, I did look through before posting, but there was very little on the Roland and Tascam as they're pretty new, so I was wondering if anyone had one, and could share some experiences.

Comment: +1, I'm yet to decide on what to purchase myself, so in a similar boat here, I even have the NTG-2 on my list too. I'm particularly interested in hearing what's said about the DR-100 Mk2! 

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at getting the Zoom H1 recorder, but a decent Shotgun Mic, and then build a Boom Pole and a Shock Mount. I searched youtube.com and came across many videos on how to build them.

I have a nady shotgun mic, it doesnt pic up the best of quality, but with some editing I can clean it up pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

We have a Marantz PMD-661 and it works really well, for the price point the mic pre-amps are quiet, and the built in mics are a lot better than I expected.  We also have the older PMD-660s which have never broken down, so I am pretty certain that the PMD-661 will be as reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, me too I'm using **Marantz PMD-661** with **RODE NTG-2** shotgun microphone.Fantastic pairing, but I recommend it.
[**Check my sound demos**](http://soundcloud.com/membrans-sound-design)